# Gradient of neural network with respect to inputs

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, automatic-differentiation

I am working on a NN with Pytorch which simply maps points from the plane into real numbers, for example

```
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(2,2),nn.ReLU(),nn.Linear(2,1))
```

What I want to do, since this network defines a map h:R^2->R, is to compute the gradient of this mapping h in the training loop. So for example

```
 for it in range(epochs):
      pred = model(X_train)
      grad = torch.autograd.grad(pred,X_train)
      ....
```

The training set has been defined as a tensor requiring the gradient. My problem is that even if the output, for each fixed point, is a scalar, since I am propagating a set of N=100 points, the output is actually a Nx1 tensor. This brings to the error: autograd can compute the gradient just of scalar functions.

In fact, trying with the little change

```
pred = torch.sum(model(X_train))
```

everything works perfectly. However I am interested in all the single gradients so, is there a way to compute all these gradients together?

Actually computing the sum as presented above gives exactly the same result I expect of course, but I wanted to know if this is the only possiblity.

Answer (score 0):

There are other possibilities but using `.sum` is the simplest way. Using `.sum()` on the final loss vector and computing `dpred/dinput` will give you the desired output. Here is why:

Since, `pred = sum(loss) = sum (f(xi))`

where `i` is the index of input `x`.

`dpred/dinput` will be a matrix `[dpred/dx0, dpred/dx1, dpred/dx...]`

Consider, `dpred/dx0`, it will be equal to `df(x0)/dx0`, since other `df(xi)/dx0` is 0.

PS: Please excuse the crappy mathematical expressions... SO does not support latex/math expressions.

Comment: Yes I see, which is as I have done, with the difference that instead of the loss, I work on the outcome of the network. I see that Latex is strangely not supported here. Thanks